# Unable To Wrap Text In Firefox 12

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a long piece of text (which i'm extracting from a database) in a table. I have no problem wrapping the text In Chrome, IE, Safari, or Opera but I cannot find a solution that will work with Firefox. I initially attemped this by inserting the text in a table cell yet this would not work with any browser, however when I inserted the text in a div this resolved the problem.

The CSS and HTML i'm using is as follows:

```
.test
{

    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;

}

<td>

    <div class = 'test'>

        ...Long Word Goes Here...

    </div>

</td>
```

Would the fact that the div is nested inside the table have anything to do with it (perhaps it is inheriting a parent property?) as I have seen a similiar example work in Firefox 12: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap

Does anyone know how to solve this problem please? It seems to be a very common one in relation to Firefox. I've viewed several similiar problems to this one on the site but i've been unable to find a solution.

Any help is much appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Strange... example in your link is wrapped in my FF12...

Comment: I tested in Firefox, Chrome, and IE. The `break-word` value only works if the element that contains the text, has a fixed width. **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/9c7Sm/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually realised what my problem was. I was using preformatted text wrapped in a pre tag and this was causing the problem. The following link was the solution for my problem: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/make-pre-text-wrap/

Apologies for this oversight and thanks for helping me out!

Comment: The <pre> tag is used to preseve the formatting from the textarea while storing it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

How is styled your table and cells? There are two very different algorithms: with and without **`table-layout: fixed;`**.
If what you see is a `td` getting larger and larger to deal with this long word, try adding this declaration to table with the width you want on the `td` parent of this `div`.

Without a fiddle or an example where we could reproduce your problem, it's hard to tell more, apart that `word-wrap: break-word;` works fine in the general case in Firefox and elsewhere.

Comment: The parent table is styled as follows:.comment
            {
            
                width:100%;
                border-style:solid;
                border-color:#A19AAA;
                border-width:1px;
                margin-top: 20px;
                table-layout:fixed;
                
            }